# get logged in ID from jwt so that only logged in user can see particular data in nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, authentication, jwt

I am using nodejs, jwt and mysql.

I want the current logged in user ID soo that I can show the data respective to it.

This is my code where SQL logic is written and here I am expecting to get a current user ID.

```
const pool = require('../../dbconfig/dbconfig');
module.exports = {
    getProfile : (callBack) => {
        var sql = 'SELECT name, shopStatus, phone, shopaddress.shopNo, shopaddress.complex, shopaddress.landmark, shopaddress.street, shopaddress.area, shopaddress.city FROM shop INNER JOIN shopaddress ON shop.id = shopaddress.shop_id WHERE shop.id = ?'

        var insertSql = [ /* how can i get ID here.. */ ]

        pool.query(sql, insertSql, (err, results, fields) => {
            if(err) {
               return callBack(err)
            }
            return callBack(null, results)
        })

    }
}
```

this happens to be jwt middleware code

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const config = require('../../config')

module.exports = {
  isAuth: (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.get("authorization");
    if (token) {
      // Remove Bearer from string
      token = token.slice(7);
      jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.json({
            status: 'error',
            message: "Invalid Token..."
          });
        } else {
          req.decoded = decoded;
          next();
        }
      });
    } else {
      return res.json({
        status: 'error',
        message: "Access Denied! Unauthorized User"
      });
    }
  }
};
```

and this is controller

```
const shopService = require('./shop.service')

module.exports = {
    shopProfile : (req, res) => {
        shopService.getProfile((err, results) => {
            if(err){
               return res.status(500).json({
                    status : 'error',
                    error : err,
                    message : 'Database connection error'
                })
            }
            return res.status(200).json({
                status:'success',
                data : results
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: you get the ID from the token value. You are supposed to generate token in such a way that includes all needed information for a user. This means the ID if this is the identifier you need. So once you have a valid token, decode it to get the information (user ID) it contains

Comment: yes I got the point, even I've placed the user ID to get the details of the user 
like wise

var token = jwt.sign({ result: results.shopId }, config.secret, {
                    expiresIn: "24h"
                })
M just not getting that how to place the code in which section soo that i get the ID. @NikosM.

Comment: You will also need to pass the ID as parameter to `shopService.getProfile` so you need to alter that method to accept one extra parameter, the ID of the user

Comment: But how can i get the current logged in user ID here
        `var insertSql = [ /* how can i get ID here.. */ ]`
can u please show me the example of it

Comment: helpppp@NikosM.

Comment: You can do for example: `getProfile : (userID, callBack) => {..}` so now you have thr userID in your method. And call `shopService.getProfile(req.decoded.ID, (err, results) => {..})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214318/discussion-between-velocity-csgo-and-nikos-m).

Comment: Dont have time to chat sorry, hope these hints give you the idea

Comment: broo. It will make my day if I get this, i am stuck on this @NikosM.